# Momentary Text Highlighting on Content Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my application, there is an element like this:

`<label id="label" class="control-label">Label (Foo)</label>`

As a result of some javascript code that response to user input, part of the element text may change:

`<label id="label" class="control-label">Label (Bar)</label>`

The javascript responsible for this change is similar to:

`label.text('Label (Bar)');`

In order to emphasize this change to the user, I would like the changed portion of the label to be momentarily highlighted. After a short period, this effect should fade out. Note that this effect is similar to that of the Elements view of the Chromium/Chrome browser's developer tools when the DOM changes.

How can I achieve this effect with html, css, jquery, javascript, and/or bootstrap?

Edit: At the very least, the entire label could be highlighted when its content changes.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to achieve such an effect yourself yet? Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#mybtn').click(function() {
  $('#label').html('Label (BAR)');
  $('#label').addClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  100% {
    background: none;
  }
}

.highlight {
  animation: highlight 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="label" class="control-label">Label (Foo)</label>
<button id="mybtn">
Click Me
</button>
```

Check it in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iNullPointer/4f71jy9w/11/)
Hope this will be helpful.